# How can I change audio track in Exo player in android

Tags: java, android, exoplayer2.x

**I have some video with two audio tracks and I want to change the audio tracks to another language during the video play.**

I have tried everything but still got no success

This is my code and I am using firebase storage to store the video.

I have searched everywhere but couldn't get the sollution.

My code is running and still didn't get any error but it's like impossible for me to change the audio tracks.

```
public class NewVideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SimpleExoPlayerView exoPlayerView;
    SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
    String videoURL;
    private ImageView selectTracksButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_video);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        selectTracksButton = findViewById(R.id.audioTrack);



        videoURL = getIntent().getStringExtra("Link");

        exoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.exo_player_view);
        try {


            BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
            TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
            exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);




            Uri videoURI = Uri.parse(videoURL);

            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
            ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoURI, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);




            exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);

            exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
            exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);


        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("MainAcvtivity"," exoplayer error "+ e.toString());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

witch ExoPlayer 2.11.7. this code work very well for me:

```
  public void setAudioTrack(int track) {
    System.out.println("setAudioTrack: "  + track);
    MappingTrackSelector.MappedTrackInfo mappedTrackInfo = Assertions.checkNotNull(trackSelector.getCurrentMappedTrackInfo());
    DefaultTrackSelector.Parameters parameters = trackSelector.getParameters();
    DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder builder = parameters.buildUpon();
    for (int rendererIndex = 0; rendererIndex < mappedTrackInfo.getRendererCount(); rendererIndex++) {
        int trackType = mappedTrackInfo.getRendererType(rendererIndex);
        if (trackType == C.TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            builder.clearSelectionOverrides(rendererIndex).setRendererDisabled(rendererIndex, false);
            int groupIndex = track -1;
            int [] tracks = {0}; 
            DefaultTrackSelector.SelectionOverride override = new DefaultTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(groupIndex,tracks);
            builder.setSelectionOverride(rendererIndex, mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(rendererIndex), override);
        }
    }
    trackSelector.setParameters(builder);
    curentAudioTrack = track;
}
```

Hope to help you.

Comment: What is the int track here @share pvv

Comment: What is the int track here

Answer (score 0):

You can use **hls video (.m3u8 extension)**  format for solution.

[offical documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/hls.html)

simple code

```
    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
    trackSelector.setParameters(
            trackSelector.getParameters().buildUpon().setMaxVideoSizeSd()
            .setPreferredTextLanguage("en")
            .setPreferredAudioLanguage("en").build());
```

you can give supported languages as parameters to the method here
also if avaible supported multi subtext you can give as parameters to the method (setPreferredTextLanguage) same way.

[languages code list](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php)

sample hls video url for you

[https://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod-multitrack/*definst*/smil:ElephantsDream/ElephantsDream.smil/playlist.m3u8](https://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod-multitrack/_definst_/smil:ElephantsDream/ElephantsDream.smil/playlist.m3u8)

this hls video supported two audio language; English and Spanish (en, es)

I hope helpful

Comment: how do i query the available audio language in the file?